# Compute the change of basis verification

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, change-of-basis

I have following two bases:

$\mathcal{B}:=\{1+X+X^2,X^2,X+X^2\}$

$\mathcal{C}:=\{1+X,1,X^2\}$

I'm then asked to create a change of basis matrix.

So that means:

$1+X=a(1+X+X^2)+b(X^2)+c(X+X^2)$

$1=a(1+X+X^2)+b(X^2)+c(X+X^2)$

$X^2=a(1+X+X^2)+b(X^2)+c(X+X^2)$

So if I put it into a matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}

So if we row reduce, we get:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}

So that means $P_{\mathcal{C}\leftarrow\mathcal{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Besides, I solved the problem through another method, and I got the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check this using the definition of a change of basis matrix. To check the first column, compute $1\times (1+X+X^2)+-1 \times X^2$, and verify that it equals the first element of $\mathcal{B}$. You can do the same with the other columns, and verify that your answer is in fact correct.

(Also, you should use $a_1,b_1,c_1$ in the first equation, $a_2,b_2,c_2$ in the second equation, and so on. $a$ can't have different values in different equations, you need to label the matrices separately.)